# Using a Node.js Npm package with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, google-translation-api

Is that possible to use an Npm package that supposed to be used in nodejs with react?

I guess it depended on the source code...
Does someone know if I can use that package:
google-translate-api
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api-v2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with lodash but instead of doing :

`const lodash = require('lodash')`

I had to use the import style :

`import * as lodash from 'lodash'`

so you might want to import it like this : `import * as translate from 'google-translate-api'`

Comment: I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the browser version of that module which solved CORS issue.

https://github.com/cjvnjde/google-translate-api-browser

Comment: Does it require  Google translate token?

Comment: It seems that the package doesn't working when I set a custom domain. 
It's causing a cors error

Comment: It shouldn't happen as it use `cors-anywhere`, what do you mean set a custom domain? You change the param in setCORS?

Comment: When I running the app through localhost it working perfectly. However, after deploying it to firebase it's not working =(
You can check it yourself on https://app.fluentlly.com

Comment: Change the url to https `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Tried it already. 
That is the error:
index.js:1 Error: BAD_NETWORK
    at index.js:128
    at async translateText (Sidebar.js:122)

net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Do you have Any solution?

Comment: `const translate = setCORS("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/");`
   
Works for me, can you post your code?